# Beginners Alias

Tags: postgresql, alias

```
SELECT *
FROM car_t
JOIN ( SELECT driver_id, gender, first_name,last_name
 FROM driver_t 
 WHERE gender = 'Male');
```

I get an error for not using Alias. Can someone help me with that ? Thank you!
I need to do a join statement with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common requirement in SQL that every derived table must have an alias (although some databases are lax about it).

Your subquery produces a derived table, that you hence need to alias:

```
SELECT * 
FROM car_t c
JOIN ( 
    SELECT driver_id, gender, first_name,last_name FROM driver_t WHERE gender = 'Male'
) d ON ???
--^ table alias
```

Notes:

- your query is clearly missing a `JOIN` condition to relate the two tables; it should appear after the `ON` keyword, that I added to the query
- the subquery is actually not necessary here; you could just join the table, then select the needed columns

```
SELECT 
    c.*,
    d.driver_id,
    d.gender,
    d.first_name,
    d.last_name 
FROM car_t c
JOIN driver_t d ON ???
WHERE d.gender = 'Male'
```

Comment: What should i put after the "ON" ? The name of a  table?

Comment: @Jamal: you put there the condition that defines the relation between the tables. Assuming that `driver_t` has a `car_id` column that refers to column `car_id` in `car_t`, that would be: `ON d.car_id = c.car_id`

Answer (score 0):

Well the error messages refers to your "derived table" (alias "subquery") which requires a name

```
SELECT *
FROM car_t
JOIN ( 
  SELECT driver_id, gender, first_name,last_name
  FROM driver_t 
  WHERE gender = 'Male'
) as x --<< the alias
```

But that will just lead you to the next error because you have no join condition.

So you need something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM car_t
JOIN ( 
  SELECT driver_id, gender, first_name,last_name
  FROM driver_t 
  WHERE gender = 'Male'
) as x on x.??? = car_t.???
```

You need to replace the `???` with the columns that link the two tables together.

---

But you don't really need the derived table anyway. You can simplify this to

```
SELECT 
FROM car_t
  JOIN driver_t as x on x.??? = car_t.??? 
WHERE x.gender = 'Male';
```